# Splice, Upload, and Re-Combine File Blobs

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

I am currently working on an upload system with a combination of Javascript and PHP.  The Javascript essentially reads a file in by splicing blobs of *cutoffSize* size (or, the remaining file size, if less).  Each splice is sent to the php script via Post.  Then, the PHP script re-assembles the file blob by blob.

However, in my implementation (as shown below), the output file is too large.  I am not sure why the file is not being written correctly, but I believe that I have localized the problem to the php script.  All of my javascript testing appears to have succeeded.  However, I have included the Javascript as well, just in case.

I believe the problem may be in the way I write/append files.  Unfortunately, I am not sure how to move forward, so I cannot investigate this further or describe in more detail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Javascript:

```
function getBigStringAndPost(files,i,p) {
    var key = $("#keyText")[0].value
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var blob = files[i].slice(p*cutoffSize,Math.min((p+1)*cutoffSize,files[i].size));
    var folderName = $("#folderInput")[0].value;

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var result = reader.result;
        console.log(result.length);
        $.post("http://brandonquinndixon.com/PHP/uploadFile.php",{
            uploadKey: key,
            doUpload: 1,
            folderName: folderName,
            splitPart: p,
            fileName: files[i].name,
            fileContents: reader.result
        },function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            if ((p+1)*cutoffSize<files[i].size) {
                currentUploaded += cutoffSize;
                updateProgressBar();
                reader.abort();
                getBigStringAndPost(files,i,p+1);
            } else {
                $("#statusDiv").html($("#statusDiv").html()+"<p class='normalP'>File: "+files[i].name+" uploaded successfully.</p>");
                currentUploaded += files[i].size%cutoffSize;
                updateProgressBar();
                reader.abort();
                loadNextFile(files,i+1);
            }
        });
    };

    reader.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        totalSizeOfFiles -= files[i].size;
        $("#statusDiv").html($("#statusDiv").html()+"<p class='normalP'>File: "+files[i].name+" could not be read.</p>");
        loadNextFile(files,i+1);
    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}
```

PHP:

```
$targetDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Downloads";
$getKey = $_POST['uploadKey'];

$data = array();
error_log("upload attempt started");

//first, check the upload key
if ($getKey !== $uploadKey) {
    $data['status'] = "failure";
    $data['message'] = "Incorrect Upload Key";
    error_log("bad key");
} else if ($_POST['doUpload'] == 1) {

    $fileName = "";
    if ($_POST['folderName']!=="") {
        $folderName = cleanInput($_POST['folderName']);
        if (!is_dir($targetDir."/".$folderName)) {
            mkdir($targetDir."/".$folderName, 0777, true);
        }

        $fileName = $targetDir."/".$folderName."/".$_POST['fileName'];
    } else {
        $fileName = $targetDir."/".$_POST['fileName'];
    }

    /*
        Don't allow executables
    */
    if (strpos($fileName,".exe") > -1 || strpos($fileName,".sh") > -1 || strpos($fileName,".deb") > -1 || strpos($fileName,".rpm") > -1) {
        $data['status'] = 'failure';
        $data['message'] = 'Executable type files are not allowed';
    } else {
        if ($_POST['splitPart'] == 0) {
            overWriteFile($fileName,$_POST['fileContents']);
            $data['type'] = 'overWrite';
            $data['details'] = 'P '.$_POST['splitPart'];
        } else {
            appendFile($fileName,$_POST['fileContents']);
            $data['type'] = 'append';
            $data['details'] = 'P '.$_POST['splitPart'];
        }

        $data['status'] = 'success';
    }
} else {
    $data['status'] = 'success';
    $data['type'] = 'none';
    error_log("success, no upload");
}

echo json_encode(array($data));

function overWriteFile($fName,$fContents) {
        $fName = lookupFile($fName);
        $file = fopen($fName,"w");
        fwrite($file,$fContents);
        fclose($file);
    }

    /*
        Append to end of file
    */
    function appendFile($fName,$fContents) {
        $fName = lookupFile($fName);
        //$file = fopen($fName,"a");
        //fwrite($file,$fContents);
        //fclose($file);
        file_put_contents($fName,$fContents,FILE_APPEND);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried an artificially low cutoff size and a smaller actual file so that it shouldn't trigger the size issue? That might narrow it down.

Comment: I have tried that, to combine multiple parts of a small file, as well as raising the cutoff to allow a large file to upload without splitting.  In both cases, the filesize is too large.  However, when I check the contents of a test text file, they are as they should be.  Images, however, lose their format.

Comment: Why are you doing this in parts rather than just uploading the entire file?

Comment: It is because in the current implementation, the Javascript reads the file into RAM, then sends it.  For larger files, the browser will kill the reader once it exceeds a certain size in memory.  This problem can be avoided by sending it in chunks.